# Add Events to multiple calendars

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

We have several calendars set up on our site...a main school calendar and also calendars for each of our teachers.  To add events to the teacher calendars their names are dropped down on the option tab...is it possible to have all as a selection so the event will show on all calendars?

Comment: Do you mean the calendar dropdown in the Calendar fieldtype/widget in the entry form? If so, unfortunately this isn't possible. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

Comment: You could consider using categories and a single calendar, instead of multiple calendars as an alternative.